# Importing static third party library

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode5

I've started iOS development this week and have run into an issue importing a third party SDK which is in the form of a static library.

This seems like it should be pretty straight forward but I can't seem to get Xcode to recognize the library.

The SDK ( due to an NDA I can't name the source) is in the form of two .a files, one of which is about 10kb and the other that is a little over 10MB. There is also an "includes" directory that has header files.

What I have done is highlight my project in the project explorer on the left, hit the "Build Phases" tab and under "Link Binary With Libraries" I add the .a file. Under build settings I go to "Search Paths" and I add the path to the includes directory under "User Header Search Paths".

Now in my project explorer I see the library I added under "Frameworks" as filename.a - however the icon is different than the other frameworks I have in that it looks like a blank document(don't know if that is relevant) and there is no arrow icon next to it that allows the framework to be expanded.

When I do an import of one of the header files e.g

```
#import "theAPI.h"
```

I get a header not found error. I know that this is one of the header files that are in the includes directory.

The steps I followed were in the XCode docs, I'm not sure what I am missing. If anyone had any suggestions on what could be going wrong here I would really appreciate it. Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure the SDK actually works and isn't corrupted ?

Comment: How are accessing the header files i.e where exactly is your "Static Library" added in the physical folder?

Comment: @Ohnomycoco , no I'm not 100% sure the SDK is not corrupt but I think it is unlikely. footyapps27 - the library is on my local file system and I've linked it under "Link Binary With Library" in "Build Phase"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like the problem is that xcode can't find your header files.

Double check your header search path.. if xcode can find it then it should auto-complete your #import statement for you.

You can also try to add the include directory into the library search path then you should be able to include headers like this:

```
#import <theAPI.h>
```

Comment: You were correct, can't believe I missed that. I had a typo in the path to the headers. Thanks much!